# funnel chart loosing colour after printing into pdf file

Tags: qlikview

I am in a situation here, I have a qlikview file that is having a funnel chart that looks like this

[image: Funnel chart in Qlikview file]

but when I print the file into pdf format it looks like this

[image: Funnel chart in pdf file]

I checked the properties of the chart but can't figure out the reason why the chart is loosing colour

Comment: I seriously doubt if SO is the right place to ask this question. You didn't ask any programming related question.

Comment: I have asked it on qlik community aswell but since I have no reply there, I am trying my luck if someone can help

Comment: In the chart properties --> Colors --> Use patterns instead colors --> "When printing" is unchecked?

Comment: yes it is unchecked and I cant check it, it is hidden

Comment: I also notice that If I change the chart type to bar chart when printing option is active but with funnel chart this option is hidden

Comment: hmm which is your QV version? Mine is 11.20 SR5 and this option is visible with the funnel chart. https://goo.gl/photos/J2D8qcpYtQkr6Wps5

Comment: I am using 11.20.12852.0 SR11 64-bit Edition, I have Multicolored visible (and I have checked that option in this case) , but When Printing and On screen are Hidden in  same way like Multicolored is hidden in your photo.

Comment: If you recreate the chart from the start in the same qvw or in different qvw is this is the same? I've seen similar behavior but when recreate the chart and its gone. If now you can try with different QV version just to eliminate this as a reason